# What does the L in chrome console signify?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome-devtools

[image: As it appears in chrome console ;]
The image above is taken from the chrome console.

It is the output representing an angular.js scope.

What does the L between the arrowhead and the opening curly brace signify ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the "class" (constructor function name) of the object being logged, *in an italic font*, and it's likely a minified name in compressed code. It's just the lowercase letter *`l`*.